# How to create a layout with different size grid theming with Views?

Tags: views, theming

I recently saw this Wordpress [website](http://www.autonews-magazine.com/?lang=nl).

I am curious on how to create such a layout with different columns for each row in views.

Can someone help me out with this what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This you can do using combination of [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels). Views will provide whatever data you want. This will be the easiest and straight.

- **Views** is for -> Fetching the data
- **Panels/DS** is for -> To arrange Display layout

**Panels**,

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized
>   layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content
>   manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content
>   within that layout.

Or instead of Panels, [Display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) also,

**Display suit**,

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files.